# No error on code but application crash when perform function. Logcat show FATAL EXCEPTION on (MainActivity.java:623)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I've been creating a Bluetooth application, everything works fine from turn On and OFF, search device, visible device, open server, set client. Everything works fine and the device could be paired. But when I want to perform data transfer using Input/OutputStream the crash begin.

The code had NO ERROR, but when performing connectedThread function it crashes. here is the code

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mySocket;
    private final InputStream myInStream;
    private final OutputStream myOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mySocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        myInStream = tmpIn;  <-------MainActivity.Java:623
        myOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int begin = 0;
        int bytes = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes += myInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
                for (int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                    if (buffer[i] == "#".getBytes()[0]) {
                        myHandler.obtainMessage(1, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                        begin = i + 1;
                        if (i == bytes - 1) {
                            bytes = 0;
                            begin = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            myOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mySocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }


    Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            int begin = (int) msg.arg1;
            int end = (int) msg.arg2;

            switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    writeMessage = writeMessage.substring(begin, end);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

The connectedThread is trigered from here

```
transferBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConnectedThread t = new ConnectedThread(socket);<------MainActivity.Java:192
                t.start();
        });
```

The Logcat show this

> 07-14 02:53:04.937  16812-16812/com.example.heszrave.bluetoothremote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.heszrave.bluetoothremote.MainActivity$ConnectedThread.(MainActivity.java:623)
>               at com.example.heszrave.bluetoothremote.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:192)

When I click on MainActivity.Java:623, it pointed to `myInStream = tmpIn;` for MainActivity.Java:192 it pointed to the firing event `ConnectedThread t = new ConnectedThread(socket);`

Comment: You have a nullpointerexception? This is a runtime exception and not a compile time exception hence the reason you didn't see an error initially. You need to figure out why ConnectThread or one of the associated variables are returning null.

Comment: Post your full logcat as I'm sure that isn't showing what is needed. It's very likely that `socket` is null. Also, this is a bad idea `catch (IOException e) {
        }` you should do something (even if just logging) when an exception is thrown.

Comment: the log cat too long by 10k character

Comment: how can i paste it ? @codeMagic

Comment: Filter by "error". But as has been pointed out, something in that Thread is `null` so you could do a little debugging and see if you can find it